# Giving Information to Database via php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mamp

I have a database setup by using phpMyAdmin within MAMP. I would now like to connect and push information to that database just to check if I am connected. I am using codeigniter as a framework for my website, and I have gone into the database.php file and edited the necessary information:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testing';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

I am an incredibly under-experienced programmer. I dont even really understand how to check if I am even connecting to the database. Anyways, where would I input php code to start pushing information to the database? If I made a php file, where would i put this file within the codeigniter framework? This is what is mainly confusing to me.

I appreciate any insight/information that anyone can provide,

Thank you.

Comment: watch this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBdqTHAGHfU, or read the manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

Any attempt to load the database driver will cause the engine to try to connect to the database. If the connection fails it will throw an error, otherwise it will continue on with the database loaded.

Just throw a `$this->load->database();` into one of your controllers and if it doens't throw an error message at you then you've set everything up correctly.

Alternatively you can autoload the database as Serigo said if you want to use it everywhere by adding it to the `$autoload['libraries']` array in `application/config/autoload.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `database` in the autoload.php

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

And write it in your controller, I think it should drop "error" if your database parameters are wrong.

```
try {
$this->load->database();
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "error";
}
```

Just saying, I'm not an expert in codeigniter.

[read this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html), it may help you